# Bash - Compare 2 filelist and show the difference

Tags: bash

I am trying to compare `filelist2` to `filelist1`. But somehow my code is not working, it always shows the first file as missing file, please assist

For example,

filelist1

```
app-663.tar.bz2
deb-663.tar.bz2
misc-663.tar.bz2
```

filelist2

```
app-663.tar.bz2
deb-663.tar.bz2
```

Here is my code

```
while IFS= read -r f; do
    if [[ -e $2/$f ]]; then
        printf '%s exists in %s\n' "$f" "$2"
    else
        printf '%s is missing in %s\n' "$f" "$2"
        exit 1
    fi
done < "$1"
```

output

> app-663.tar.bz2 is missing in filelist2.txt

Comment: You are checking whether file named `filelist2.txt/app-663.tar.bz2` (`[[ -e $2/$f ]]`) exists. It is not comparing 2 lists. If you need to compare 2 text files, then `diff filelist{1,2}.txt`, or `colordiff filelist{1,2}.txt` can do. If you want to know whether text `app-663.tar.bz2` (`$f`) exists inside a text file `filelist2.txt` (`$2`), then `grep -x "$f" "$2"` would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` is  your friend :

```
awk 'NR==FNR{rec[$0];next}!($0 in rec)' filelist2 filelist1
```

**Output**

```
misc-663.tar.bz2
```

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

---

<sup>**Note:** If you're starting with `awk`, check this [[book]](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Usm1AAAACAAJ&dq=Beginners+guide+to+awk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4rbbwhe3YAhWBmZQKHePoAwUQ6AEILDAB)</sup>